# Make bread with flour different from the starter

Tags: sourdough, sourdough-starter

I have been able to cultivate a strong sourdough starter with whole wheat flour and  semolina flour.

Now I want to make a bread with all purpose flour, show should I proceed ?

Get this already active started and make my bread or feed it with flour until it gets used to ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your starter should have no problem working with other flours, you don't need to acclimatize it or anything. Just use it as you ordinarily would.

I would suggest bread flour rather than AP, the higher gluten content will give better structure.

Comment: Thank you very much. About the flour type, where I live the bread flour is called Tipo 1, but its kinda hard to find this one for purchase. What about Tipo00 ? Its better than AP ?

Comment: @AndréRoggeriCampos, your comment is probably worth turning into a new question.

Comment: There are several questions about type00 flour on the site already, it may be worth searching for that first before asking something new.

Answer (score 1):

I have a rye starter which I use with strong wheat flour, or with a rye/wheat mixture.  But I don't add anything to the starter except rye and water, half-and-half.

Comment: John, welcome! Please clarify with an [edit]: Is that an answer (then it should say something like “it works”) or an “I have the same question, just with another kind of starter”? The latter wouldn’t be acceptable in the answer section (see [answer] for details). The [tour] and [help] will explain more about how the site works.

Comment: This! Keep your starter fed with the same flour. The amount of starter in the final bread is usually neglectible, so it doesn't really matter what the starters flour was.